# Initial condition checking with Userdefaults is failing

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, option-type

Check the condition and store the value from user default into variable and assign to textfield.

Initial condition in user default it will be empty I am checking the condition using guard if its empty (nil) assigning cost value to "" empty String else assign the value from user default which its stored from given defaultskey.cost

```
class  FirstViewControll : ViewController
var costValue: String?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       costValue! = userDefault.value(forKey: defaultsKeys.cost) as! String
            guard costValue != nil else {
                self.textField?.text = ""
                return
            }
           self.textField?.text = costValue!

}
```

App crashes for failing in optional value unwrap
**Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

I assume that written a valid condition code.

Comment: costValue = userDefault.value(forKey: defaultsKeys.cost) as? String. Just replace this line worked perfect!  Need to know after replacing  "!"  with "?" the string accept with optionals.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check if there is a value in UserDefaults.

```
if let value = userDefault.value(forKey: defaultsKeys.cost) as? String {
   // there is a value 
   costValue = value
} else {
   self.textField?.text = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed guard checked with condition not exist ?? "" its worked fine!

```
self.textField?.text = userDefault.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.cost) ?? ""
```

No idea is this good approach or not!